How to chose a crystal report in combobox
I am trying in my winforms to add a combobox which will display 2 different crystal reports. When i click on one report it will show me the data from that report. How can i do that? I am using VS 2022 and Oracle database.
I have only created 2 Crystal report but how can i put them in combobox? The reports name are Employee.rpt and WorkPlace.rpt
